# Machine Learning Application In Computer Network area

Tags: networking, machine-learning, adhoc

I am currently working in computer networking area, more specifically working in developing real time application for ad hoc network.Recently I have worked in machine learning and I love it.I want to know is there any way I could work with both (Computer network and machine learning).I have tried a lot but did not find yet.

Answer (score 1):

Machine learning is tricky, most people just think of it as using library functions. One needs to develop *differentiation across ML algorithms (not only use cases)*. So make sure to join university course and some hands on at problem solving not program writing.